# ReferenceError: Cannot access ' ' before initialization

Tags: discord.js

My code;

```
        const mentionMember = message.mentions.members.first();
        let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ");
        if (!reason) return message.channel.send(banEmbederrormessage);
```

banEmbederrormessage

```
        let banEmbederrormessage = new discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor(0xdb2727)
        .setDescription(`
        Bir hata oluştu.
        **[KULLANIM]** +ban @mention sebep
        `);
```

Terminal error;

```
(node:3248) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: Cannot access 'banEmbederrormessage' before initialization
    at Object.run (C:\Users\gtaplus bot\commands\ban.js:13:50)
```

I am developing ban command. Terminal returns this error after using the ban command.

Comment: We need more code, where is `banEmbederrormessage` coming from?

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros I added their code to the question.

Comment: You can't use a variable before it's definition

Comment: Cheers for updating your question but we still don't know where you defined your `banEmbederrormessage` variable.

Comment: @ZsoltMeszaros Look carefully at the code. Anyway, problem solved, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place the definition *first*.

```js
        let banEmbederrormessage = new discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor(0xdb2727)
        .setDescription(`
        Bir hata oluştu.
        **[KULLANIM]** +ban @mention sebep
        `);
        const mentionMember = message.mentions.members.first();
        let reason = args.slice(1).join(" ");
        if (!reason) return message.channel.send(banEmbederrormessage);
```